# Как избавиться от зависимостей в хэдерах?

Tags: c++, library, зависимости

Например, я пишу класс, который зависит от каких-то библиотек, т.е. их типов. Внутри класса у меня приватные поля для этих данных. Я не хочу, чтобы пользователь в принципе знал о том, что я использовал. Не для того, чтобы скрыть как секрет, а чтобы не засорять ему статический анализ, и избавить его от конфликтов неймспейсов (редко, но бывает). **Возможно ли это сделать?**

Comment: Воспользуйтесь идиомой Pimpl (указатель на реализацию). Т.е. все внутренности заменяются указателем на нечто, а что именно - уже в файле реализации. Минус - лишняя косвенность + самому легко запутаться...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

да, называется pImpl. Это общеизвестная идиома. В хедере только интерфейс, который пробрасывает запросы к внутреннему объекту, который объявлен полностью в cpp классе.

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl
- https://habr.com/ru/post/111602/